# Как будет работать join с повторениями SQL

Tags: sql, join

Есть две таблицы : tab1 tab2

```
trans#  data    price
1   01.10.2021  500
2   01.10.2021  600
3   02.10.2021  700
```

```
seller# data
1   01.10.2021
2   01.10.2021
```

Что вернет ?

```
Select tab1.trans#, tab1.data, tab1.price, tab2.seller# 
from tab1 
LEFT JOIN tab2 on tab1.data = tab2.data
```

Comment: по идее должно вернуть `2*2 + 1` записей, но быстрее будет попробовать. Это можно сделать в любом `DB fiddle`...

Comment: Подскажите, я новичок , где проще и быстрее моделировать базы из табличек, чтобы потом проверять запросы?

Comment: Да это ж на пальцах всё легко просчитывается. `LEFT JOIN` - это когда берутся по очереди (никакая группировка не происходит) все записи из таблицы слева и им сопоставляются подходящие записи из таблицы справа (опять же без группировки), либо null-ы, если ничего не удалось сопоставить. Поэтому две записи из левой таблицы размножатся об две записи правой таблицы, а ещё одна запись из левой таблицы будет напечатана с null-ами в качестве сопоставления из правой таблицы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всегда можно воспользоваться [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

[Ваш запрос](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96c677/1) вернет 5 записей, так как по вхождению `data=01.10.2021` и `trans=1` будет найдено две записи (2 строки), затем тоже самое будет найдено для `data=01.10.2021` и `trans=2` и  `trans=3` будет с null в join, так как совпадений нет

Answer (score 3):

Вернется 5 записей, можете попробовать самостоятельно:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/01096/3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]